# CSS: How to get lines to "line up" accross different columns?

Tags: css

I am creating an HTML web page, which comprises of three vertical columns. The columns contain different content - including form elements (selects etc).

However, I would like the text lines to "line up" accross all three columns (not sure if I'm using the correct terminolgy here).

At the moment, the text in columns 1, 2 and three (using the 1st column text as a reference), are not "lined up" - that is to say that if a virtual horizontal line was to be drawn accross the three columns, the text on column 1 would be on the line (since it is the reference column), and the text in columns 2 and 3 are NOT on the same horizontal line.

Is there a CSS rule I can use to ensure that the texts "line up" accross all columns - even though some columns may contain form controls, images etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's normal to have them not lined up, they might have titles and other content in between, but anyways if you want to line things up equally you do `line-height:25px;` /*or whatever you want*/, it would be easier if you pasted some code here or at jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to split your columns on the horizontal as well. So, instead of having:

```
<div class="col1">forms, images + text</div>
<div class="col2">forms, images + text</div>
<div class="col3">forms, images + text</div>
```

you can have the following:

```
<div class="top-col1">forms, images</div>
<div class="top-col2">forms, images</div>
<div class="top-col3">forms, images</div>
// I assume the columns are floated so you'll probably have
// something like <br class="clear"/> here
<div class="bottom-col1">text</div>
<div class="bottom-col2">text</div>
<div class="bottom-col3">text</div>
```